# PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault, azure-data-lake-gen2

```
com.databricks.common.client.DatabricksServiceHttpClientException:
PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault https://azkv*.vault.azure.net/.
Wrapped Message:
  Status code 403,
  {"error":
    {"code":"Forbidden","message":
       "Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\n
        If role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.\r\n
        Caller: name=AzureDatabricks;appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;oid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9945/\r\n
        Action: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/getSecret/action'\r\n
        Resource: '/subscriptions/6b60a61d-3e92-4501-8794-fd7725066113/resourcegroups/streamproject/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/azkv*/secrets/clientsecret'\r\n
        Assignment: (not found)\r\n
        DecisionReason: 'DeniedWithNoValidRBAC' \r\n
        Vault: azkv*;location=eastus\r\n",
      "innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByRbac"}
    }
  }
```

I have been trying to mount ADLS to databricks using service principal and secret scope. I can't access the key vault it seems.

How could I solve this?

Comment: im also facing this error com.databricks.common.client.DatabricksServiceHttpClientException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault https://dbsacctkv01.vault.azure.net/ .. but when i navigate to Access Policies it says access policies not availabe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the identity in the access policy blade
[image]

then you set the required permissions for the secret scope
[image]

later select the corresponding service principal of your databrick
[image]

And then you create the policy
[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using Access policies seems to be discuraged (legacy). Is there another way?

Answer (score 5):

I just faced a similar issue. Here is how I solved it. It might help you too.

I'm using RBAC in my Key Vault. I had to give the "Key Vault Administrator" role to my Databricks Application. The problem I was having is that I couldn't find the Databricks Application when listing its object id in the Key Vault's Access control. Therefore, I followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/troubleshooting?tabs=bicep#:%7E:text=az%20role%20assignment%20create%20%2D%2Dassignee%2Dobject%2Did%2011111111%2D1111%2D1111%2D1111%2D111111111111%20%20%2D%2Drole%20%22Contributor%22%20%2D%2Dscope%20%22/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D%22). After adding my role through the Azure CLI:

```
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111  --role "Key Vault Administrator" --scope "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}"
```

Then I stopped getting the RBAC error. This was independent of using a Service Principal. Good luck!

Comment: your answer helped to resolve a similar issue.
Thanks

Comment: If your Databricks is only reading secrets, you can also use the "Key Vault Secrets User" role with read-only permissions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check your Key-vault permission model under your Key Vault -> Settings -> Access Configuration on Azure portal.

Azure keyvault mainly allows key vault access using two permission models.

1. Azure role-based access control (recommended)
2. Vault access policy

[image]

If you are using Azure role-based access control (recommended), make sure that you have given 'Key Vault Administrator' role to your service principal from Access Control (IAM) section of your key vault.

[image]

If you are using Vault access policy, make sure that you have added policy for your service principal with necessary permissions under Access Policies section of your key vault.

[image]

Mostly, this might fix your issue.

Comment: vault access policy is working fine. but Azure role-based access control is not working.

Comment: At a time only 1 will work, depends on your key vault's permission model.